# Minimum latency to acquire an image?

Tags: pi-2

I have a real-time requirement to capture a frame at the same instance as another event.  I have a digital signal available to trigger the acquisition of an image.  The frame rate is on the order of one frame every 10 seconds or so.

Processing time is really not important.  I just need to be able to capture an image quite near temporally to the event.  I would like this to be in the 15mS range.  Is this possible?